# Are human infants inherently frightened by anything?

Tags: psychology

Naïve question - feel free to shoot it down.

To the best of my knowledge an infant doesn't really 'shrink' from something without first trying it. Even the action of looking at the fierce expression is undertaken without qualm - squalling comes later (if at all!)

Are human infants inherently frightened by anything?

Comment: this is more a developmental psychology question.  I have kids and they are quite easily feeling afraid and threatened.  Being left alone without their parents or other close family is very common.

Comment: Loud noises are something that infants of any age certainly are not fond of?